# How to use Django backend templet variable in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django-templates

I want to use backend data in the js file.

```
return render(request, "class.html", {'all_classes':all_class})
```

I want to use it in the JS 'all_classes'.
I know for the HTML -

```
<select name="subject_class" type="text" class="form-control" required >
      {% for class in all_classes %}
          <option value="{{ class.class_name }}">{{ class.class_name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
</select>
```

but please give me an idea for the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
in your html page create script tag

```
<body>
.
.
.
.
.
<script>
    var all_class= {{ all_classes }};  
    console.log("all_classes",all_classes)
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I am using javascript in another file, not in the same HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

you can construct the body of the script tag in the same way

```
<script>
    {% for item in some_variables %}
    let item.name=item.value; 
    {% endfor %}
<script>
```

Comment: I am using javascript in another file not in same HTML file.